# Visual C++ using Console: Char/String compatibility issues with while loop

Tags: c++

```
    cout << "Would you like to make another transaction? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> repeat_transaction;
    static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction);
    while (repeat_transaction != 'y' && repeat_transaction != 'n')
    {
        cout << "Invalid selection: Please enter y or n";
        cin >> repeat_transaction;
        static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction);
    }
```

During the Invalid selection loop, I once accidentally pressed "mn". I noticed the console read out `Invalid selection...`, So, it did in fact finish and re-enter the while loop. However, after this the console terminated the program. If you enter a single character 'a' or 'y' or 'n' it acts just as it should. Ending or not ending. This was before I attempted to use static_cast to force the truncation of the user input.

Comment: Show the definition of `repeat_transaction`, and if this code is part of a loop or there is any earlier input, show that too

Comment: `static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction);` doesn't do anything, it is like writing `x + 1;` .

Comment: What is _Visual Basic C++_ ?

Comment: @jpw he probably means visual c++...

Comment: `static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction)` doesn't "force the truncation of the user input". It is just a compile-time conversion of the variable `repeat_transaction` from whatever type it is (which you do not specify in your question) into `char`. And BTW, since you are not assigning it to anything (e.g., `char x = static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction)`) it has no effect on your program anyway.

Comment: "Visual C++ using Console: Char/String compatibility issues with while loop"

Comment: I never wrote Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you managed to get this program to compile I can only assume that `repeat_transaction` was specified as a `char` and not a `std::string`.

When you use `cin` to get a character it only gets one character but it doesn't flush the buffer. I believe you understand this issue since you wrote *This was before I attempted to use static_cast to force the truncation of the user input.* . You can attempt to use `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead of `static_cast<char>(repeat_transaction);` after each call to `cin >> repeat_transaction;` . There are downsides to this. If you enter 'mn' it will work as expected. It reads the `m` which is not `y` or `n` and then flushes the extra characters until it finds end of line `\n`. If you do `nm`, `n` will match and the `m` will be thrown away. So in that case it will accept `nm` as valid and exit the loop.

There are other ways that may be easier and give you the effect *closer* to what you are looking for. Instead of reading a character at a time you can read an entire line into a string using `getline` (See the C++ [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for more information). You can then check if the length of the string is not equal to `1` character. If it's not length `1` then it is invalid input. If it is `1` then you want to check for `y` and `n`. Although basic (and not overly complex) this code would do a *reasonable* job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string repeat_transaction;
    cout << "Would you like to make another transaction? (y/n)" << endl;
    getline(cin, repeat_transaction);

    while (repeat_transaction.length() != 1 || (repeat_transaction != "y" && repeat_transaction != "n"))
    {
        cout << "Invalid selection: Please enter y or n";
        getline(cin, repeat_transaction);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I said *reasonable* job since one deficiency you might see is that you want to trim white spaces from the beginning and end. If someone enters `n` or `y` with a `space` or `tab` in front it will be seen as invalid (whitespace at the end would be similar). This may not be an issue for you, but I thought I would mention it.

On a final note, you may have noticed I used `using namespace std;`. I did so to match what was in the original question. However, this is normally considered bad practice and should be avoided. These [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/1452738#1452738) try to explain the issues. It is better to not do it and prepend all standard library references with `std::`. For example `string` would be `std::string`, `cin` would be `std::cin` etc.

Comment: Thank you, the string method should work well. I understand that std:: is preferred and better for compatibility, but this is a simple midterm project for a first semester computer class. I use system() as well, which I understand to be a bad idea for production code. But, for my own personal uses on Windows and within the limits of my knowledge and the course, it won't become an issue.